# Microsoft SurfaceBook doesn't want to connect to external Monitor

Tags: external-display, microsoft-surface, docking-station

### **  **UPDATE MARCH 1ST**  **

I might have find the solution to my issues.
I have found on Reddit some people that had the same problem as me. apparently, you need an Active Cable & an active adapter to make it work. I've already ordered an active cable, so I'll see if this fix the problem.

---

I have a Microsoft Surface Book and I cannot use my Surface Docking Station to connect an external monitor. It doesn't shows up in any settings. However, I can directly connect a monitor from the laptop, but then I can't put it on charge, as the charging connector is too big.

I have a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI Converter, then I use a HDMI to DisplayPort cable to connect my monitor.

My monitor is a ViewSonic VG2439m-LED. I tried using a VGA cable, but I need a HDMI to VGA adapter, so it goes:

- MiniDiplayPort -> HDMI
- HDMI -> VGA
- VGA -> Screen

It seems like the adapters are heating then the monitor stops showing any image. So I rather not use this technique. It is also waaaayyyy too long.

REM: I CANNOT use this technique with the Docking Station, as it does not show any image at all.

I tried to update the drivers, I tried a Microsoft Surface Diag, and tried to connect it to another monitor, it does the same (Work with MiniDisplayPort to HDMI and HDMI to screen, but doesn't from the dock).

I also tested the USB Ports to see if my Hub was broken, but it's not. I can see USB Keys and my Surface is charging when it's plugged on the hub.

**My questions are:**

> ```
>  1. What can cause that my Docking Station isn't displaying anything at all & how to fix it ?     
>  2. Can I use DisplayPort as a Monitor Input ?
>  3. VGA, DVI or DisplayPort: Which one should I choose ?
> ```

Please refer to this *"excel worksheet"*, it contains all test I've done:

```
                                                 From…              
Using MiniDP to…                  Surface Book            Hub           
HDMI -> DisplayPort (Screen)        Nothing             Nothing         
HDMI -> VGA -> VGA (Screen)     Image for a minute      Nothing 

Tested:                 
Current Hub Drivers     Nothing change              
Latest Hub Drivers      Nothing Change              
No Drivers              Nothing change              
Old Drivers             Nothing change              

Changed screen resolution   Nothing change              


                                                       From…                
With another monitor using…              Surface Book             Hub           
MiniDP -> HDMI -> HDMI (Screen)         Works perfectly         Nothing         
MiniDP -> HDMI -> VGA -> VGA (Screen)   Not tried although I cannot use this monitor for work, as it's a projector. I've only used it for tests.
```

Feel free to tell me any other tests I could try.

[image: Monitor's box]

Comment: I also tested the USB Ports to see if my Hub was broken, but it's not. I can see USB Keys and my Surface is charging when it's plugged on the hub. - But what proves the display pass through is working on the dock?

Comment: Why would they add such a Mini DisplayPort to the Hub if it doesn't work ? It's an official Microsoft Surface Docking Station, It's not an AfterMarket or Ebay one.

Comment: @Darksoulpk68, he isn't saying it isn't supposed to work, just that testing the USB port doesn't test the MiniDP port, so this port can possibly be just  **broken**.